# How to troubleshoot an older build in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, realm

I have a published app that is crashing after upgrade, due to a problem with the Realm database.

My code currently in xcode doesn't have the problem.

How can I run the old build in xcode so I can troubleshoot?

Comment: Do you have any source control? Just roll back to the release version? Or you could try to install the archive that you uploaded but you won't get any useful break points from the crash without the old code.

Comment: I do have source control. So, I assume after rollback I could return to the new code?

Comment: Yeah. Just checkout the old commit. Checkout not rollback. Then when you found the bug you can check out the latest commit.

Comment: Yeah use tags to mark releases to make them easier to find.  Once you have release 1.0 and want to make release 1.1 with additional features then branch off 1.0 and start a 1.1 branch.  If errors occur on 1.0 before 1.1 is released you can cherry pick commits from 1.1 over to 1.0 and re-release.

Comment: Here is a suggestion for the future to check if your Realm DB need a migration or not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333959/detect-if-realm-io-db-needs-migration-if-so-destroy-it